# Is 'localhost' considered fully qualified?

Tags: networking, localhost, domain-name

In the absence of a domain name, is the name `localhost` considered fully qualified? Or is `localhost` always considered unqualified?

```
$ hostname --fqdn
debian-q500

$ ping debian-q500
PING debian-q500 (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from debian-q500 (127.0.1.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from debian-q500 (127.0.1.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
...

$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
...
```

The reason I am asking is I am looking at a standard doc that specifically calls out a FQDN. And a FQDN is slightly different than a DNS name from the RFCs (I believe its RFC 1035):

```
$ dnsdomainname 
$
```

Under the DNS system, I believe `localhost` would be considered a non-DNS local name; but it might satisfy the FQDN requirement if listed as `localhost.` (note the trailing dot).

In fact, I get different results when adding a trailing dot on the machine named `debian-q500`:

```
$ ping debian-q500.
ping: unknown host debian-q500.
$ ping localhost.
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`localhost` is not fully qualified; `localhost.localdomain.` is.

The main key for an FQDN is the terminating full-stop.  `hostname.example.com` is not fully-qualified; `hostname.example.com.` is.  Common convention, if not official standard, says that an FQDN ought to be `host.domain.` rather than simply `host.`, but again, the important thing is the `.` at the end to truly by fully-qualified.

Comment: [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/269838/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hostname-and-a-fully-qualified-domain-name) SE page has a more detailed explanation.

Comment: You might do well to also explain [that `ping` isn't a DNS diagnosis tool](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/nslookup-results-different-to-ping.html) and that at least one proxy DNS server software hardwires the `A` resource record set for `localhost.`.

Comment: I agree that `ping` is not a good DNS test, but it can be considered a name resolution (writ large) test, in that using `ping` handles `/etc/hosts` entries and other mechanisms in addition to DNS.